# How to get values on one dataframe based on the position of a value in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with the same size.

```
df1
1 5 3
6 5 1
2 4 9

df2
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

I want to get the corresponding value on df2 that is in the same position as the maximum value of each row in df1. For example, row 0 has element [0,1] as its max, so I'd like to get [0,1] from df2 in return

Desired result would be:

```
df3
b
d
i
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use for loops. `numpy` can be handy here

```
vals = df2.values[np.arange(len(df2)), df1.values.argmax(1)]
```

Of course, can `df3 = pd.DataFrame(vals)`

```
    col
0   b
1   d
2   i
```

Comment: Can you give the reason of not using loops?

Comment: @thelogicalkoan If you are using loops with pandas, then you haven't yet grasped why the library (and others such as `numpy`) exist in the first place. Instead of lecturing you with boring, massive amounts of text, I'll just recommend you to watch a [small video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw) - which happen to be very very entertaining - that will build your intuition on the practicality of vectorization and the difference in performance you get when vectorizing vs not vectorizing

Answer (score 1):

```
S=df1.idxmax(axis=0)
p=0
for a in range(len(df1):

     df3.iloc(['a','0'])=df2.iloc([S[p],0])
     p+=1
```

Try the code:

Comment: Always avoid for loops when using pandas.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(df1.idxmax()):
...     print(df2.iloc[i, j])
... 
b
d
i
```

[`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) gives the id of the maximum value in the dataframe, either row-wise or column-wise.

Comment: Always avoid for loops when using pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has two parts:
**1-** Finding the maximum value of each row
**2-** Choosing the maximum column of each row with values found in step one

You can easily use [lookup](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) function. The first argument is finding the maximum column in rows(step one), and the second is the selection(step two)

```
df2.lookup(range(len(df1)), df1.idxmax()) #output => array(['b', 'd', 'i'], dtype=object)
```

If array does not work for you, you can also create data frame from these values if by simply passing it to pd.DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(df2.lookup(range(len(df1)), df1.idxmax()))
```

One good feature of this solution is avoiding loops which makes it efficient.